# Linear layout's weight not working on phone, working fine in xml preview in android studio

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-xml

I have used layout_weight in LinearLayout in my xml file. The preview is fine, but when i run the app in a phone, the view is different. 
This is the xml file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <!--<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/title_dashboard"
            android:textSize="25sp"/>-->

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">

        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/ivBrandImage"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:id="@+id/tBrandName"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivBrandImage"
            android:text="Email name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_brand_name"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tBrandName"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivBrandImage"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_brand_name"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:id="@+id/switchBrand"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_dashboard_card"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_dashboard"
            android:text="@string/textview_pending_approvals"
            />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_dashboard_card"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_dashboard"
            android:text="@string/textview_pending_approvals"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_dashboard_card"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_dashboard"
            android:text="@string/textview_pending_approvals"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Following is the xml preview:

[image: xml preview]

And here is the actual screenshot of same on phone:

[image: screenshot]

I am not able to figure out, why is the actual screen different from the xml preview. Can someone please tell what is the mistake here?

Comment: how are you inflating this xml layout?

Comment: This is a layout of what? Obviously, parental view of your `LinearLayout` has `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` property. So, what is the hierarchy of layouts?

Comment: This is one of the fragments of a navigation drawer. I have created a navigation drawer activity from the studio's inbuilt options. So, the hierarchy is somewhat like, 

DrawerLayout(activity_main.xml) > CoordinatorLayout(app_bar_main.xml) > CardView (whose code I've pasted in the question). 

All the three parts are in different xml files. "include" attribute is used to include files in the hierarchy I've mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the parent layout of xml file from LinearLayut to RelativeLayout solved the issue. Of course, some minor changes were required to achieve the goal. Here is the xml file, which runs fine on the phone too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/cvDashboardHeader">

        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="16dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:id="@+id/ivBrandImage"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"/>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:id="@+id/tBrandName"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivBrandImage"
                android:text="Email name"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_brand_name"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tBrandName"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivBrandImage"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_brand_name"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:id="@+id/switchBrand"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cvDashboardHeader">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_dashboard_card"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_dashboard"
                android:text="@string/textview_pending_approvals"
                />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_dashboard_card"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_dashboard"
                android:text="@string/textview_pending_approvals"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_dashboard_card"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_dashboard"
                android:text="@string/textview_pending_approvals"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

please make it for all resolution like hdpi ,xhdip,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi.
please select your tested device resolution from here then test it again.

[image]

Comment: The layout looks fine in all the resolutions in the studio. But, doesn't work out in the device. I'm using Moto E2 (Lollipop)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Use `android:layout_height="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` for the first ***CardView***(which contains the Image of Android logo).

Comment: That would make the whole card disappear. weight should be greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_dashboard"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>-->

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="16dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:id="@+id/ivBrandImage"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:id="@+id/tBrandName"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivBrandImage"
                android:text="Email name"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/button_padding"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tBrandName"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivBrandImage"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/button_padding"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:id="@+id/switchBrand"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/button_padding"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/button_padding"
            android:text="fjdkjk"
            />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/button_padding"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/button_padding"
            android:text="jdfkjffjkjk"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/button_padding"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/button_padding"
            android:text="jkgjk"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

import it -

compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'

working fine in MI4

Comment: I've already included compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0' in the gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

In case of LinearLayout.It is demo through below code .You can solve your problem.
Use below code.

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_kpis"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color_dark"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_13" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_target"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/txtbox_text_color_darek"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_13" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_actual"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/txtbox_text_color_darek"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_13" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

In case of Relatvie Layout
Use Below code.

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_kpis"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/kpi"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_16" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_target"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/traget"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_16" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_actual"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:text="@string/actual"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_16" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```